# Typescript build with project references fails with `Output file has not been built from source file` even though it was built

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a project that references a shared project alongside it. 
My configs look like:

`projectA/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../shared",
      "prepend": true
    }
  ]
}
```

`shared/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "build/out.js",
    "composite": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

running `ts -b` from inside `projectA` yields:

```
src/index.ts:6:24 - error TS6305: Output file '.../shared/build/out.d.ts' has not been built from source file '.../shared/src/index.ts'.

6 import DummyClass from '../../shared/src';
```

**Even though this file is indeed created.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @james I too am running into this. I don't have a full solution, but it appears circular references may be involved.
See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26691) for a start (the page I was on before my search led to here)

Comment: I've actually changed my approach here if this helps anyway.

I do have a shared library project to a similar setup, but as a far of my ProjectA I've added a build.sh. I adjusted my package.json to include a "build" script that executes build.sh. Build.sh then copies my needed libraries into project A and runs a webpack with a tsloader so i'm actually pulling these into the project locally.

Probably not the greatest but it got me moving.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the solution was to run `npx tsc -b` on the referenced-project directory, which requires [npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx) to tell the typescript compiler (`tsc`) to build (`-b`). You can probably add this step to your compilation pipeline.

Perhaps an easier method is to tell typescript to do that itself by running `tsc -b` in the npm build script of your main project (you can learn more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html)).

Comment: This is such a save. Great thanks!